# Bug on homepage navigating to my newsletter subscriptions

Tags: bug

From http://travel.stackexchange.com:

- On right-hand sidebar, under 'love this site', clicked on 'see an example newsletter'
- In the pop-up, clicked on 'subscriptions page on stackexchange.com' in small text at the bottom.
- Took me to youtube.com instead, specifically http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZZ7oFKsKzY. I don't think this is actually malware, but certainly not where I wanted to go!

Comment: I think it's a feature, not a bug. The SE Team didn't put the real links in the example newsletter but a link to an annoying youtube video.

Comment: Hahahaham what an annoying video!! the video has 38,072,079 views... the rumor says most are in therapy...